# Install Arm cross compilation for GCC4.8 in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, arm, cross-compiling, gcc4.8

First off, I'm new to Linux and have installed ubuntu 12.04 as a VM to compile code to an ARM dev. kit. Since only the 12.04 version is supported I'm unable to install e.g. latest ubuntu or another distribution.

My code uses parts of c++11 and I need to use gcc4.8, which is installed and working. However, when I try to get the package for the cross-compiler gcc-4.8-armhf-cross, I get an error. I'm quite sure it is the one linked from here:
    https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-4.8-armhf-cross

I usually just use 'sudo apt-get package', which has worked well for now. But, I can't get this package, or I get errors on missing dependencies when in the aptitude console program.

I would appreciate if someone can explain what I'm doing wrong and how to do it correctly?

Thanks in advance

Henrik

Answer (score 0):

It's not *quite* the answer you asked for, but this is what "just works" for me on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS:

Near the bottom of [Linaro's downloads page](http://www.linaro.org/downloads/) you'll find "Binaries" - download the latest "linaro-toolchain-binaries 4.8" for Linux (currently the [13.11 release](http://releases.linaro.org/13.11/components/toolchain/binaries/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.8-2013.11_linux.tar.xz)), untar it into a location of your choice, (optionally) add the `bin` directory to your `$PATH`, and you should be good to go.

Oh, and in case it needs to be said - the ones for 64-bit and big endian are of the "if you have to ask, then you don't need them" variety ;)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I might have to go into the "don't ask" category. I'm running a 64-bit release, and can't execute the ones from the link, since I think they are 32-bit versions. Now, do I install 32-bit runtime on my distribution, or should I choose a different version? I only need little endian versions, so I'm safe here.